# Problem with setValue returning Range - want to pull "MMM, yy" from a date as TEXT only

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets, setvalue

I'd love your help with this because I keep making parts of it work but then I try to fix one problem and it causes another sigh

I have a test sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DaZTUvVsS1cbw2rGjFkOqgWMXcqJcbnbBE4oYjjgJRQ/edit#gid=91590629) where I have already attempted this in Apps Script. Unfortunately I couldn't paste my script here for some reason, but I've put it on a new tab in the Test Sheet.

Basically I have a nested on Edit formula.
col A is Date
col B is Month
col C is Duration (trigger column)

What I'm trying to do:
Any edit in Duration column

- Col A receives today's date UNLESS a date is already typed in
- col B pulls the month from Col A to display as text "MMM, yy"

I've managed t oget this almost working a couple of times but I run into some issues:

- Sometimes set Value returns "Range"
- set Value displays what I want but the actual cell data shows the date
- the formula works if a new date is entered by the script but not on existing dates

As I say any help would be freaking amazing TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're struggling because it's all inside that onEdit. You may consider dividing them in two different things. onEdit and the rest. I joined your other two functions, but you can obviosly separate them again:

```
function onEdit(e) 
{
  if(e.range.getColumn() == 3){
  setDates();}
}

function setDates(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
  var editrow = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow()
  var today = sheet.getRange(editrow,1)
  var value = new Date(new Date())
  var month = sheet.getRange(editrow,2)

  if(today.getValue() !== "") {
    month.setValue(today.getValue()).setNumberFormat("MMM-yy")
     }
  else {
    today.setValue(value).setNumberFormat('dd/MM/yyyy')
    month.setValue(value).setNumberFormat("MMM-yy").setNumberFormat('@') //now you change it to text with that last condition
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for that! You've really helped me tidy up my script.

Unfortunately, while the cell displays the format I want, it still has the cell value of the timestamp. I need the cell value to be text.

Don't suppose you have any ideas there? :)

Comment: Just add .setNumberFormat('@') after month.setValue(value).setNumberFormat("MMM-yy") --> month.setValue(value).setNumberFormat("MMM-yy").setNumberFormat('@')

Comment: Beauty! thank you so much for your help that is perfect!